# Styles are partially lost when кeload the page

Tags: angular

I really need your help. I'm trying to make an adaptive layout for the component: if the width of the browser is less than 900px, for the `canvas` tag set `width = 4`, and if more `width = 8`. The fact is that the styles work as they should, but if I cut the browser window less by 900px and reload the page, the styles are shown as for the desktop version, and if I re-expand the window more than 900px, it works normally for desktop view. How can this be fixed? Thank you very much

html

```
<canvas
  [width]="widthOfWindow < 900 ? canvasMobileWidth : canvasDesktopWidth"
  height="5"
  baseChart
  [datasets]="radarChartData"
  [labels]="radarChartLabels"
  [chartType]="radarChartType"
  [options]="radarOptions"
  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
></canvas>
```

ts

```
canvasMobileWidth: 4
canvasDesktopWidth: 8
widthOfWindow: number = window.innerWidth;

public radarOptions: any = {
legend: {
  labels: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 30,
  },
  position: 'bottom',
},
title: {
  display: true,
  text: 'Competence Matrix Chart',
  fontSize: 20,
},
tooltips: {
  mode: 'index',
  callbacks: {
    title: (tooltipItem: any, data: any) =>
      data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index],

    label: (tooltipItem: any, data: any) =>
      data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label,
  },
},
scale: {
  pointLabels: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  ticks: {
    suggestedMin: 0,
    suggestedMax: 5,
    stepSize: 1,
    z: 1,
    showLabelBackdrop: false,
  },
 },
};

ngOnInit(): void {
 if (this.widthOfWindow < 900) {
  this.radarOptions.width = this.canvasDesktopWidth
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to watch for the window size changes, you need to subscribe to the observable that observes the size change. Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-angular6-qqxkqc